# Build facet with group id and value on Array object

Tags: mongodb, facet

How should a facet with group be created on an array?
In below example, we have item array

```
{
    "_id": 12345,
    "itemDetails": {
        "item": [
            {
                "id": "51",
                "name": "Chips",
                "categoryId": "101",
                "categoryName": "Solid"
            },
            {
                "id": "52",
                "name": "Apple cider",
                "categoryId": "102",
                "categoryName": "Liquid"
            },
            {
                "id": "52",
                "name": "Mango Juice",
                "categoryId": "103",
                "categoryName": "Liquid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The outcome I'm aiming for

```
{
    "items": 
    [
        {
            "id": 51,
            "count": 1,
            "key": "Solid"
        },
        {
            "id": 52,
            "count": 2,
            "key": "Liquid"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried like this but no success. Below query returns empty name and it is not grouping on id. Please suggest.

```
[
    {
        "$group": {
            "id": "$itemDetails.item.id",
            "count": {
                "$count": {}
            },
            "key": {
                "$first": "$itemDetails.item.name"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is missing an unwind stage immediately before the facet.

```
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$itemDetails",
    },
  }
```

Rest all worked as expected.